# How to get a new form to appear when registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When you click on a submit button with value="continue" on a form, it brings up a new form for one to fill so registration can continue.

Comment: The title is not a place to put the question. You have to put the question inside the question body. Besides that, this question is nothing more than a plz-gimme-the-codez-question and thus too broad. Please try something, then come back and ask a question with what problem you ran into that you cannot solve, what the intended behaviour is and give code that can be used to reproduce that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to take the user to the registration form? Take him to another page, name it `registration.php` and give him the form there.

Make a `<form>` tag and then give it the attribute `action` inside which, you will give the address of your new page, lets say `registration.php`

```
<form method = "POST" action = "registration.php">
<input type = "submit" name = "sub" value = "continue">
</form>
```

Now when you click on it, it will take you to the new page i.e. `registration.php`